# How to prevent a site from allowing its users to provide their own templates

Tags: django, security, templates, web, web-applications

I am developing a web app and in the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/) I read this:

> The template system isn’t safe against untrusted template authors. For example, a site shouldn’t allow its users to provide their own templates.

Given the fact that I won't be allowing the end-user to upload any code, I reckon that the above would only be possible if the user would somehow gain access to the server and upload his (malicious) templates or by an XSS attack.

Is there something else I am missing here and should be aware of? Are there any additional measures (except for securing my server and looking out for XSS attacks) I must take in order to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template code doesn't have to be in a file. So it's possible to create a django website where users can submit django template code in a regular form, just like you can use markdown here at StackOverflow. The template code would be stored in a model field in the database.

Developers might be tempted to use django template code in such a way. For example if you built blogging site or forum using django.

You don't need any special measures to protect against this. It can only be exploited if you create some way for users to submit template code which you execute on the server.

Comment: I'm not planning on providing the user any way of uplading any content, so I think I'm ok on that front. Thank you for your answer.